# How to color particular cells given row index and column name in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df of shape (100,10) and a dictionary columns_to_color for each row.

```
columns_to_color = {
  0: ['col1', 'col2', 'col9'],  # Columns 1, 2 and 9 should be colored for row 0
  1: ['col1', 'col5', 'col8'],  # Columns 1, 5 and 8 should be colored for row 1
  2: ['col3', 'col4', 'col7'],  # Columns 3, 4 and 7 should be colored for row 2
  .......
```

How do I color those particular cell for each row of that column? and then save it to excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`.style.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html) like so:

```
df.style.apply(
    lambda row: [
        'font-weight: bold' if col in columns_to_color[row.name] else ''
        for col in row.index],
    axis=1)
```

(I'm using bold just for convenience.)

Then to convert to Excel, use [`.to_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.to_excel.html).

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({f'col{n}': range(10*n, 10*n + 3) for n in range(10)})
```

After `apply` (in my IDE):

[image: screenshot showing table with bold cells]

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`df.style.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.apply.html) and apply a lambda function to each row (`axis=1`), where we check if its values are present in the corresponding list from the dict:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# for reproducibility
np.random.seed(0)

columns_to_color = {0: ['col1', 'col2', 'col9'],
                    1: ['col1', 'col5', 'col8'],
                    2: ['col3', 'col4', 'col7']}

# sample df
cols = [f'col{i}' for i in range(1, 10)]
data = np.random.rand(4, 9)

df = pd.DataFrame(data=data, columns=cols)

# for each row (`axis=1`) get the list from dict, and check if `row.index` values
# (i.e. now, the col names) are present in the list; if so: add background-color
# (using `dict.get` avoids error if index value is not present as dict key)

df_styled = df.style.apply(
    lambda row: np.where(row.index.isin(columns_to_color.get(row.name, [])),
                         'background-color: yellow', ''),
    axis=1
)

# save to excel
df_styled.to_excel('myfile.xlsx')
```

**Output**

[image: excel output]